# Why does this awk script that runs on CentOS not run on Ubuntu?

Tags: bash, scripts, text-processing, awk

*(for reference, the code is likely also here:
https://github.com/garyexplains/examples
which is probably a better source than a video.)*

---

Would there be any reason why [this simple script](https://youtu.be/jJ02kEETw70) on CentOS wouldn't run on Ubuntu?

```
[nsaunders@rolly awk]$ 
[nsaunders@rolly awk]$ awk -f loop.awk numbers.txt 
1 2 3 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 

[nsaunders@rolly awk]$ 
[nsaunders@rolly awk]$ cat loop.awk 
func printlist(n) {
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++) {
        printf("%d ",i)
    }
    printf("\n")
}


{printlist($1)}

[nsaunders@rolly awk]$ 
[nsaunders@rolly awk]$ cat numbers.txt 
3
7
12
15
16
31

[nsaunders@rolly awk]$
```

I'm getting:

```
awk: loop.awk: line 11: function printlist never defined
awk: loop.awk: line 11: function printlist never defined
```

awk version on Ubuntu:

```
mawk 1.3.4 20200120
Copyright 2008-2019,2020, Thomas E. Dickey
Copyright 1991-1996,2014, Michael D. Brennan

random-funcs:       srandom/random
regex-funcs:        internal
compiled limits:
sprintf buffer      8192
maximum-integer     2147483647
```

And on the CentOS machine:

```
[nsaunders@rolly ~]$ 
[nsaunders@rolly ~]$ awk -W version
GNU Awk 4.2.1, API: 2.0 (GNU MPFR 3.1.6-p2, GNU MP 6.1.2)
Copyright (C) 1989, 1991-2018 Free Software Foundation.

This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
the Free Software Foundation; either version 3 of the License, or
(at your option) any later version.

This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
GNU General Public License for more details.

You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
along with this program. If not, see http://www.gnu.org/licenses/.
[nsaunders@rolly ~]$
```

isn't `awk` pretty much `awk` regardless of what machine you're on?

Comment: `isn't awk pretty much awk` - as you can see on one it's `mawk` and the other is `GNU Awk`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As noted in the [The GNU Awk User’s Guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#index-functions-6)

> In many awk implementations, including gawk, the keyword `function` may
> be abbreviated `func`. (c.e.) However, POSIX only specifies the use of
> the keyword `function`.

So the error is possibly because the implementation of `awk` on your Ubuntu system is `mawk`, or that something (such as a `POSIXLY_CORRECT` environment variable) is affecting how `gawk` behaves on your system.

Ubuntu used to ship with `mawk` as the default `awk` - but as far as I know, all currently supported versions use `gawk` by default. If you installed `mawk` via the packaqge management system, you should be able to use the `update-alternatives` mechanism to query/set the default ex.

```
update-alternatives --query awk

sudo update-alternatives --config awk
```

Comment: I just installed `gawk` and it ran fine with the `awk` command, but certainly it's good to know there are variants.  Now I have `GNU awk` 5.0.1 installed.

Answer (score 9):

> isn't awk pretty much awk regardless of what machine you're on?

No, and you may even have multiple implementations on the same system. `gawk` (GNU Awk) has a number of features not present in `mawk`. The one you've run into isn't the only one. [The `gawk` documentation contains a list of common features that differ across major AWK implementations.](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Common-Extensions.html)

As [**steeldriver says**](https://askubuntu.com/a/1250111/22949), using `func` as an abbreviation for `function` is supported by some but not all AWK implementations. To solve this particular problem, the best thing to do is just change `func` to `function`. With that single change, your script works with `mawk` as well as `gawk`.

**If for some reason you can't or don't wish to do that**, or if you need other nonstandard functionality that `gawk` provides but `mawk` doesn't, you can use `gawk`, which is provided by the `gawk` package.

```bsh
gawk -f loop.awk numbers.txt
```

As shown in steeldriver's answer, you can use `update-alternatives` to make `awk` resolve to `gawk` rather than `mawk` (or that may happen automatically when you install `gawk`).

**However, you're using `awk -f`, so if you're willing to add [a shebang line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix))** to the top of your AWK script and mark the script executable (`chmod +x loop.awk`), then you can have it specify which interpreter ought to be used:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

func printlist(n) {
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++) {
        printf("%d ",i)
    }
    printf("\n")
}

{printlist($1)}
```

You would then run the script with the command:

```bsh
./loop.awk numbers.txt
```

Then other scripts remain unaffected.

For this tiny script with a single occurrence of the `func` keyword that can be written as `function`, adding a shebang probably isn't your best choice, unless you were going to do that anyway. For more complex situations where you need `gawk` features not present in `mawk`, though, I suggest considering it. Adding a shebang also has the benefit of clarifying what implementation of AWK you wish to be used, and a script for which this doesn't matter and that is written to be portable can have a `#!/usr/bin/awk -f` shebang.

(Of course, scripts with such shebangs aren't totally portable in the broader sense, since they assume `awk` is in `/usr/bin`.)

Comment: The nonportability mentioned in your last (parenthetical) paragraph can be reduced somewhat by using `env`.  For example, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418245/invoking-a-script-which-has-an-awk-shebang-with-parameters-vars), showing how to pass the `-f` with an `env` shebang.

Comment: @EricTowers `env -S` is not portable (though more than one `env` implementation  does support `-S`). I'm not sure whether it's more or less portable, in practice, than assuming `awk` is in `/usr/bin`.